# Django view function getting called twice for one GET request

Tags: python, django, get, django-views, django-urls

I have a url path defined as follows:

```
re_path(r'installapp/(.+)', views.install_app, name='install-app')
```

This URL path triggers a view function install_app. When a GET request is made to this URL path, the view function is triggered twice instead of once.

How to prevent calling of view function twice for one GET request.

Comment: Is the second call a redirect?

Comment: @Sayse - I do have a redirect url as follows:return HttpResponseRedirect('https://' + settings.AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN + '/' + settings.AWS_LOCATION + "/" + path)

Comment: I meant the second call to this endpoint, in your network tab on chrome, is one a 200 and one a 300?

Comment: Yes one a 200 and one a 300 @Sayse